# How do I send an authorization token at header when I am using grooy

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to to the same thing like this curl command line

curl -H 'Authorization: token this_is_my_token' this_is_my_url

```
final DataUrl = new URL("this_is_my_url?access_token=this_is_my_token"
getList new JsonSlurper().parse(DataUrl.newReader())
```

but it's not working

which I've tried was

```
def DataUrl =new GetMethod("this_is_my_url");
DataUrl.setRequestHeader("Authorization",token this_is_my_token)
getList new JsonSlurper().parse(DataUrl.newReader())
```

Comment: why you are not using native jenkins plugin? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax doesn't look correct, for example following line.

```
DataUrl.setRequestHeader("Authorization",token + "this_is_my_token")
```

I have used the following method.

```
def accessToken = "ACCESS_TOKEN" // If you want to Base64 encode use "ACCESS_TOKEN".bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
def get = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xxxx/something/hosts").openConnection();
get.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token " + accessToken)
def content = get.getInputStream().getText()
```

Comment: if I need to access the data in the Jason , can I still use getText()? or there is another methodI can use?